# Any other option is there without using Oracle Analytical function

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

can someone help me to resolve this?

```
CREATE TABLE TT (
     A NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
     B VARCHAR2(5)
);

insert into tt values (11,'A'); 
insert into tt values (12,'A'); 
insert into tt values (13,'B'); 
insert into tt values (14,'B'); 
insert into tt values (15,'C'); 
insert into tt values (16,'D'); 
insert into tt values (17,'E'); 
insert into tt values (18,'E'); 
insert into tt values (19,'F'); 
insert into tt values (20,'F'); 

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM TT; 

+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
|11 | A |
|12 | A |
|13 | B |
|14 | B |
|15 | C |
|16 | D |
|17 | E |
|18 | E |
|19 | F |
|20 | F |
+---+---+
```

My requirement is what are the 'B' column has mapped more than one of 'A' columns Like (value ‘E’ has mapped two rows in column of ‘A’) 
o/p

```
+---+
| A |
+---+
| 11| 
| 12| 
| 13| 
| 14| 
| 17| 
| 18| 
| 19| 
| 20| 
+---+
```

I've achieved using below analytical query. I want to know whether it’s possible to archive using without analytical fucntion.

```
select a
from (SELECT tt.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by b) cnt
      FROM TT
     )
where cnt >= 2;
```

---

Comment: Why don't you want to use analytic functions?

Comment: Its fine, but I want to know any other option to achieve the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the candidates using a group by:

```
select a 
from tt
where B in (
            select B
            from tt
            group by b
            having count(*) >= 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough with aggregations:

```
select a
from tt 
where b in (select b from tt group by b having count(*) > 1);
```

As a note, you can avoid the use of aggregation, because Oracle provides the `rowid` pseudocolumn:

```
select a
from tt
where exists (select 1
              from tt tt2
              where tt2.b = tt.b and tt2.rowid <> tt.rowid
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a from temp a where  exists ( select null from temp b where a.b = b.b group by b having count(1) >= 2)
```

This is alternate solution.i think you cannot avoid use of aggregate function in this case.

Comment: You can avoid the aggregation.

Comment: yes Gordon saw the solution you gave without using aggregate function.. :-)